# Spring & Security: limit uploads to authenticated users

Tags: spring, security, file-upload, spring-security, user-roles

I'm facing a security problem regarding file uploads.
How do I limit file uploads to specific user roles?
I'm using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`, but it is uploading the file first and then checking the role. You can especially see this when file upload size is exceeded. User will get an upload size exceeded exception instead of redirecting to the login-form.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@Secured("ROLE_USER") // added this just to see if it makes a difference, it doesn't
@RequestMapping(value = "/self/upload", produces = "application/json")
public class JsonUserSelfUpload {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/form-data")
public ModelAndView fileUpload(
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile inputFile,
        @RequestParam(value = "param1", defaultValue = "") String type,
        HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws Exception {

    ...
    }

}
```

Anyone know how to secure file uploads to specific roles?

Edit, to be more specific:
I want to reject uploads if user is not authenticated. By reject I mean, close connection before the upload actually finishes. Not sure if spring is capable in doing this or I'd need a filter to reject uploads (multipart).

Update:
Tried with a filter with no success either.
Seems like one has no way to close the connection.
This is what my filter looks like:

```
public class RestrictUploadFilter implements Filter{

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String contentType = request.getContentType();
    if (HttpMethods.POST.equals(request.getMethod()) && contentType != null && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("multipart/form-data") > -1) {
        UserSession session = SpringHelper.getUserSession();
        if (session != null && session.getRoles().contains(UserRole.USER)) {
            // user is allowed to upload
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            // access denied
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN_403);
            response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Try using `@PreAuthorize` in the `Service` class methods instead of `Controller`. Move the file Upload implementation code to a `Service` class method and secure that method with `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: @SanjayRawat this doesn't make sense, since `MultipartFile inputFile` is coming from the `Controller`. If the `Service` is getting called within the `Controller`, the file was uploaded already. I want to prevent upload mechanism to non authorizated users.

Comment: No, it depends on your implementation. As I said earlier you'd have to move your implementation to service class method. Your controller method should only get the multipartfile as input and pass it to the service class method as File argument and then in your service class method you should write code to save it. Now service class method being secured by `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` would be executed only if the user has that permitted role. Lemme know if you still have any question.

Comment: It seems like there is no solution for my question. Files are always first uploaded and then the controller is called. Imagine someone is uploading 1GB file, waiting and finally getting an "Access Denied" message. Do you get my question now? I wanted to reject multipart uploads BEFORE the controller or service is getting called. I don't need to secure the service, as securing the controller is giving me the same result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh I got it. I didn't consider the file size. You can restrict access to that url itself. If you are using Java Config then look for security configurations, it is something like `http.antmatchers("url/tobe/protected").permit().hasrole("Admin")`. I am not sure if the syntax or method chain is like this, just Google it you'd know.

Comment: Actually its `.antMatchers("url/tobe/protected/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach. I'm actually using xml configuration.

Comment: Same results.
Actually the configuration `<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/v1/self/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />` is doing the same thing as setting `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` on a controller. If you set `@PreAuthorize` on controller, the intercept-url is getting overwritten.

Additional note: as I already said, there seems to be no way to reject uploads via spring. It must be rejected by the server itself. Just like file-size-limit, which must be set on server to let it actually reject the request and close the connection (403 error).

Comment: Sorry, I mean error code 413.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107075/discussion-between-sanjay-rawat-and-arny).